# Specific topics on Tensorflow for CNN

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I have a mini project for my new course in Tensorflow for this semester with random topics. Since I have some background on Convolution Neuron Network, I intend to use it for my project. My computer can only run **CPU** version of TensorFlow.

However, as a new bee, I realize that there are a lot of topics such that MNIST, CIFAR-10, etc, thus I don't know which suitable topic I should pick out from them. I only have **two weeks left**. It would be great if the topic is not too complicated but too not easy for study because it matchs my intermediate level.

In your experience, could you give me some advice about the specific topic I should do for my project?

Moreover, it would be better if in this topic I can provide my own data to test my training, because my professor said that it is a plus point to get A grade in my project.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think that to answer this question you need to properly evaluate the marking criteria for your project. However, I can give you a brief overview of what you've just mentioned.

**MNIST**: MNIST is a Optical Character Recognition task for individual numbers 0-9 in images size 28px square. This is considered the "Hello World" of CNNs. It's pretty basic and might be too simplistic for your requirements. Hard to gauge without more information. Nonetheless, this will run pretty quickly with CPU Tensorflow and the online tutorial is pretty good.

**CIFAR-10**: CIFAR is a much bigger dataset of objects and vehicles. The image sizes are 32px square so individual image processing isn't too bad. But the dataset is very large and your CPU might struggle with it. It takes a long time to train. You could try training on a reduced dataset but I don't know how that would go. Again, depends on your course requirements.

**Flowers-Poets**: There is the Tensorflow for Poets re-training example which might not be suitable for your course, you could use the flowers dataset to build your own model.

**Build-your-own-model**: You could use tf.Layers to build your own network and experiment with it. tf.Layers is pretty easy to use. Alternatively you could look at the new Estimators API that will automate a lot of the training processes for you. There are a number of tutorials (of varying quality) on the Tensorflow website.

I hope that helps give you a run-down of what's out there. Other datasets to look at are PASCAL VOC and imageNet (however they are huge!). Models to look at experimenting with may include VGG-16 and AlexNet.

Comment: @ JCooke: Thankyou very much. Your summary is valuable for me. As you mentioned, CNN are widely used in image processing area, and the important remark here is the input of CNN need to be presented as a matrix. I also search on the internet and I realize that there are a lot of source code I can learn. However, I think in order to make something different with them,it would be better if I apply CNN to another field.

Comment: @ JCooke: The first thing I think about is to train **Boston house** problem (I think it's already familiar with you). In this problem, 9 features of input will be consider to calculate the average point as output. Have you tried this training before?  I don't know whether CNN can be applied and efficient in this case, or not ? because the input size seem very small in comparing with MNIST or CIFAR-10.

Comment: CNNs are pretty much limited to images (with some exceptions). If I recall correctly, the Boston House Prices set is more of a linear regression problem. You won't be able to do that with CNNs.

Comment: @ JCooke. Thanks very much, it sounds strugle for me. Do you know any application of CNNs other than for images?

Comment: I don't think so. The point of CNNs is that they are for vision tasks. If that's what your project is based on, CNNs, then you should probably consider doing them. I can't advise you on what to do for your course unfortunately. Perhaps go through your requirements again and research your options and see what you find. Good luck!

Comment: @ JCooke: thanks for your answer. I will think more about my research.